# Python - Why does bytes object contain entry: ' /ty" '

Tags: python, byte

I connect to a TCP-Server via the socket module, and expect to get the following hexadecimals as response:
`01 03 02 02 09 79 22`, or as the bytes object would write it: `/x01/x03/x02/x02/x09/x79/x22`

However, instead I receive: `/x01/x03/x02/x02/ty"`. (Note the `"` is part of it too)

Funny part is, when I use `.hex()` on the returned bytes object, I get the correct value returned.

My question is, what is that `ty"` and what does it stand for?

Comment: ``\x09`` is a tab character, ``\t``. ``\x22`` is a quote character `"`. You seem to be mixing up forward and backslashes in your question.

Comment: And `chr(0x79)` is `'y'`. It's just the representation of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's showing you the ascii values.

Hex 09 - tab in ascii.

Hex 79 - y in ascii.

Hex 22 - " in ascii.